# stripping extra text qualifier from a CSV

Tags: vba, ms-access, powershell, csv

I have a CSV that has certain fields separated by the " symbol as a TextQualifier.

See below for example. Note that each integer (eg. 1,2,3 etc) is supposed to be a string. the qualified strings are surrounded by the " symbol.

```
1,2,3,"qualifiedString1",4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,"qualifiedString2""
```

Notice how the last qualified string has a " symbol as part of the string.

Can you suggest an elegant way to automate the cleaning of the CSV to eliminate redundant " qualifiers?

I have the following technologies at my disposal: POSH/BAT scripting, VBA, Access.

Comment: isn't replacing `""` with `"` not enough? or am I missing something here

Comment: @mehow - you're right. i deleted the suggestion in my original post after i realized that there are many instances of empty qualified strings in the CSV.

Comment: can you show more of that csv file im not quite understanding what needs to be removed and what needs to be left untouched. Ie show what the csv looks like originally and then what you would like it to look like after the *cleaning*

Comment: i don't think adding more sample text from the CSV would help clarify. i just need to find qualified strings that have the " symbol as part of the string, and remove the " symbol.

Comment: Ok, why not read all into a variant array, iterate replacing the `""` with `"` and writing it back to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
(get-content file.txt -ReadCount 0) -replace '([^,]")"','$1' |
 set-content newfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! Can you please point me to where to learn more about this portion of the script? `'([^,]")"','$1' |
`

Comment: can anyone explain this? i can't find anything online.

Comment: Sorry I counldn't get back to you right away (work happens), but I see you got your question answered on another thread.

Comment: thanks for replying. i have another question for you. how would i change the logic in the regular expression in order to remove the extra " symbol from the a random position in the qualified string? for example, the record is `"samp"lerecord"`