# translate logic in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, syntax, scripting

For context, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659314/stripping-extra-text-qualifier-from-a-csv) SO post.

full script:

`(get-content file.txt -ReadCount 0) -replace '([^,]")"','$1' |
 set-content newfile.txt`

I am specifically looking for a translation of the logic in this portion of the script:

`'([^,]")"','$1' |`

Can someone please either explain the logic/syntax, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks somewhat like a regular expression to me.

Comment: Can you please explain the operators in the search pattern? I can't find the meaning of the `^` symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'([^,]")"'` is a regular expression that matches any character except a comma followed by two consecutive double quotes. The parentheses group the first character and the first double quote.

`'$1'` is a back-reference to the group in the match, which in the replacement means "replace the match with just the first group", e.g. in a string `foo""bar` the sequence `o""` would be replaced with just `o"`, thus removing the second double quote.

`|` is a pipe that feeds the result of the replacement into the next cmdlet in the pipeline (`Set-Content newfile.txt`).

Answer (score 2):

```
'([^,]")"','$1'
```

Let's break this into two pieces the regex pattern `'([^,]")"'` and the replacement text `'$1'`. The `()` in the regex pattern creates an unnamed capture group that is referenced in the replacement text via `$1` i.e. it is the first (and only in this case) set of parens.  What is matched & captured in this capture group is any character except a comma followed by a double quote that is also followed by another double quote outside of the capture group.  So it eliminates one of two consecutive double quotes unless the first is preceded by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

the ^ symbol matches the beginning of a string.
Great references [here](http://regex101.com/) and [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) that pretty well explain everything.
Intro to Regex in Power shell [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings.aspx).

when the ^ symbol appears in brackets [] it will match anything not including what follows the carrot

Comment: Ok. Are you able to translate the logic expressed here: `'([^,]")"','$1' ` ?

Comment: `^` does not match beginning of string when in a character class `[...]`. Inside the `[]` it matches a literal caret character.

Comment: @Eris Both of you are wrong. Inside square brackets the caret inverts the character class. `[^,]` means "any character except a comma".

Comment: Oh yes, the negation when its the First character in a class, but not when it's later. Magic-meaning ftw!