# stripping extra text qualifier from a CSV - part 2

Tags: powershell, csv, syntax, data-cleaning

For part 1, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659314/stripping-extra-text-qualifier-from-a-csv)

I have a CSV that has certain fields separated by the `"` symbol as a TextQualifier.

See below for example. Note that each integer (eg. 1,2,3 etc) is supposed to be a string. the qualified strings are surrounded by the `"` symbol.

`1,2,3,"qualifiedString1",4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,"qualifiedString2""`

Notice how the last qualified string has a `"` symbol as part of the string.

User @mjolinor suggested this powershell script, which works to fix the above scenario, but it does not fix the "Part 2" scenario below.

```
(get-content file.txt -ReadCount 0) -replace '([^,]")"','$1' |
 set-content newfile.txt
```

**Here is part 2 of the question. I need a solution for this:**
The extra `"` symbol can appear randomly in the string. Here's another example:

`1,2,3,"qualifiedString1",4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,"qualifiedS"tring2"`

Can you suggest an elegant way to automate the cleaning of the CSV to eliminate redundant `"` qualifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a different regex:

```
(get-content file.txt -ReadCount 0) -replace '(?<!,)"(?!,|$)',''|
 set-content newfile.txt
```

That one will replace any double quote that is not immediately preceeded by a comma, or followed by either a comma or the end of the line.

```
$text = '1,2,3,"qualifiedString1",4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,"qualifiedS"tring2"'
$text -replace '(?<!,)"(?!,|$)',''

1,2,3,"qualifiedString1",4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,"qualifiedString2"
```